# xmlvm for iPhone apps in java?

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c

Does this method work well for developing apps in windows?
Any testimonial or [examples](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-develop-iphone-applications-in-java/) of apps developed in java using [xmlvm](http://www.xmlvm.org/overview/)?

Looking for the best free method to develop apps in windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring whether or not using xmlvm to develop apps for iPhone is a good idea at all, this will not let you develop iPhone apps on Windows unless you are using a jailbroken device. Xmlvm generates Objective-C from their xml that then needs to be compiled. While you could setup an appropriate toolchain on Windows, you would have no way to actually sign the app with your development cert since the signing tool is only available on OS X.

So, in short, you could use it to develop apps under windows for a jailbroken phone, but it require setting up an entire Objective-C toolchain as a prerequisite anyway.